# Send cookies with curl

Tags: cookies, curl

I am using curl to retrieve cookies like so:

```
curl -c cookies.txt url
```

then I parse the cookie I want from the cookies.txt file and send the request again with the cookie

```
curl -b "name=value" url
```

Is this the correct way to send the cookie?
Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 105):

You can use -b to specify a cookie file to read the cookies from as well.

In many situations using [-c](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-c) and [-b](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-b) to the same file is what you want:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt http://example.com
```

**Further**

Using only -c will make curl start with no cookies but still parse and understand cookies and if redirects or multiple URLs are used, it will then use the received cookies within the single invoke before it writes them all to the output file in the end.

The -b option feeds a set of initial cookies into curl so that it knows about them at start, and it activates curl's cookie parser so that it'll parse and use incoming cookies as well.

**See Also**

The [cookies chapter](https://everything.curl.dev/http/cookies) in the *Everything curl* book.

Comment: I wish that the man page for `--cookie-jar` didn't say "This  command  line  option  will activate the cookie engine that makes curl record **and use** cookies." [emphasis mine]  Since that makes it sound like just `--cookie-jar` will lead to cookies being sent, which is false.

Comment: @blahdiblah: it's true. if you use --cookie-jar for a command line that first receives cookies then follow a redirect to a second page, it will use the cookies from the first page (assuming they match etc). It just won't read any initial cookies from any file.

Comment: Yes, the man page is misleading. I thought I was sending cookies just by using the -c option as well until I used -v and saw that it wasn't sending them.

Comment: Could you share the format of the cookies.txt? How does it look like?

Comment: man file is clearer now: `NOTE  that  the file specified with -b, --cookie is only used as input. No cookies will be stored in the file. To store  cookies,
use  the -c, --cookie-jar option or you could even save the HTTP
headers to a file using -D, --dump-header!`

Answer (score 17):

`.example.com TRUE / FALSE 1560211200 MY_VARIABLE MY_VALUE`

The cookies file format apparently consists of a line per cookie and each line consists of the following seven tab-delimited fields:

- domain - The domain that created AND that can read the variable.
- flag - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if all machines within a given domain can access the variable. This value is set automatically by the browser, depending on the value you set for domain.
- path - The path within the domain that the variable is valid for.
- secure - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if a secure connection with the domain is needed to access the variable.
- expiration - The UNIX time that the variable will expire on. UNIX time is defined as the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.
- name - The name of the variable.
- value - The value of the variable.

From http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/#3.5

Comment: Notice that the values in the file must be separated with a tab, not a space.

Answer (score 11):

if you have Firebug installed on Firefox, just open the url. In the network panel, right-click and select Copy as cURL. You can see all curl parameters for this web call.

Answer (score 1):

Very annoying, no cookie file exmpale on the official website https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-cookies.

Finnaly, I find it does not work, if your file content is just copyied like this

```
foo1=bar;foo2=bar2
```

I gusess the format must looks  the style said by @Agustí Sánchez
. You can test it by -c to create a cookie file on a website.

So try this way, it works

```
curl -H "Cookie:`cat ./my.cookie`"   http://xxxx.com
```

You can just copy the cookie from chrome console network tab.