# How to use cURL to send Cookies?

Tags: rest, session, curl, flask, session-cookies

I read that [sending cookies with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181785/send-cookies-with-curl) works, but not for me.

I have a REST endpoint like this:

```
class LoginResource(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        print(session)
        if 'USER_TOKEN' in session:
            return 'OK'
        return 'not authorized', 401
```

When I try to access the endpoint, it refuses:

```
curl -v -b ~/Downloads/cookies.txt -c ~/Downloads/cookies.txt http://127.0.0.1:5000/
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 5000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 401 UNAUTHORIZED
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 16
< Server: Werkzeug/0.8.3 Python/2.7.2
< Date: Sun, 14 Apr 2013 04:45:45 GMT
<
* Closing connection #0
"not authorized"%
```

Where my `~/Downloads/cookies.txt` is:

```
cat ~/Downloads/cookies.txt
USER_TOKEN=in
```

and the server receives nothing:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2013 21:43:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2013 21:45:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 -
<SecureCookieSession {}>
<SecureCookieSession {}>
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2013 21:45:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 -
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: I think adding the `-c` option tells `curl` to use your cookie file as the output cookie jar, which might not be what you want.

Comment: the one with `-b` option alone also not working, giving same error :(

Comment: the format of the `-b` cookie file is not just `var=value`, it should be the same as the format of the cookie jar written using `-c`. Go to a site that sends cookies with this option, and take a look at the resulting file.

Comment: The -b cookie_file should either be in Netscape/Mozilla format or plain HTTP headers. Here's an example of plain http headers:

Set-cookie: cookie_name=cookie_value;

This is the bare minimum. Don't forget the semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 713, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
curl -v --cookie "USER_TOKEN=Yes" http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

I could see the value in backend using

```
print(request.cookies)
```

Comment: As long as you never, ever have a boolean for a user token as a cookie, given that they can just authenticate themselves without logging in that way.

Comment: According to the man page, for option `-b, --cookie`, e.g. `curl -b <file-or-pairs>`, if the argument is a string having the `'='` symbol, it's passed as is, otherwise it's treated as a filename to read cookie from.

Comment: multiple cookies can be set with semicolons `--cookie "key1=val1;key2=val2;..."`

Comment: For sending multiple cookies, I had to put a space after `;` (I am using a mac)
Eg: `--cookie "key1=val1; key2=val2"`

Answer (score 119):

You can refer to https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html for a complete tutorial of how to work with cookies. You can use

```
curl -c /path/to/cookiefile http://yourhost/
```

to write to a cookie file and start engine and to use cookie you can use

```
curl -b /path/to/cookiefile  http://yourhost/
```

to read cookies from and start the cookie engine, or if it isn't a file it will pass on the given string.

Comment: IMO you did not enhance on the official doc which is clear as mud - __beside the overloading__ of the `-b` flag what is the essential diff between `-c` & `-b` they both start the engine and point to a cookie file?

Comment: @nhed `-c` *writes* to the cookie file, `-b` reads from it.  So when sending credentials for a login form you would specify `-c` to write the resulting cookie to a file, then you would use `-b` to read from and include the cookie in your next request.

Comment: Or do `curl -b cookiefile -c cookiefile https://yourhost/` to read *and* write to the same cookie store like browsers do.

Answer (score 54):

You are using a wrong format in your cookie file. As [curl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html) states, it uses an old Netscape cookie file format, which is different from the format used by web browsers. If you need to create a curl cookie file manually, [this post](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2005-03/0099.html) should help you. In your example the file should contain following line

```
127.0.0.1   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   USER_TOKEN  in
```

having 7 TAB-separated fields meaning *domain*, *tailmatch*, *path*, *secure*, *expires*, *name*, *value*.

Comment: Yes, this is the cURL cookie format. These are TABS and not SPACES.

Comment: This should be marked as the official answer, since this truly addresses the point as to why @daydreamer's setup was failing.

Answer (score 12):

`curl -H @<header_file> <host>`

Since curl 7.55 headers from file are supported with `@<file>`

`echo 'Cookie: USER_TOKEN=Yes' > /tmp/cookie`

`curl -H @/tmp/cookie <host>`

[docs & commit](https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/84b9458837551a2749b45d924089f2015415a324#diff-1b753ed826c4bd5e71a106a38205440a0d1f0b4029afc8f4695a9ecd2d98e559L3)

Answer (score 6):

If you have made that request in your application already, and see it logged in Google Dev Tools, you can use the copy cURL command from the context menu when right-clicking on the request in the network tab. Copy -> Copy as cURL.
It will contain all headers, cookies, etc..

Comment: This solution is much easier if the cookie you need is already available via a browser.  +1

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Debian, and I was unable to use tilde for the path. Originally I was using

```
curl -c "~/cookie" http://localhost:5000/login -d username=myname password=mypassword
```

I had to change this to:

```
curl -c "/tmp/cookie" http://localhost:5000/login -d username=myname password=mypassword
```

`-c` creates the cookie, `-b` uses the cookie

so then I'd use for instance:

```
curl -b "/tmp/cookie" http://localhost:5000/getData
```

Comment: `~` is not expanded to `$HOME` if it's put within quotes, in which case it will be treated as a literal tilde. ;]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using json.

CURL:

```
curl -c /tmp/cookie -X POST -d '{"chave":"email","valor":"hvescovi@hotmail.com"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:5000/set

curl -b "/tmp/cookie" -d '{"chave":"email"}' -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json"  localhost:5000/get

curl -b "/tmp/cookie" -d '{"chave":"email"}' -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:5000/delete
```

PYTHON CODE:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, jsonify
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = '$#EWFGHJUI*&DEGBHYJU&Y%T#RYJHG%##RU&U'
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

@app.route('/')
def padrao():
    return 'backend server-side.'
    
@app.route('/set', methods=['POST'])
def set():
    resposta = jsonify({"resultado": "ok", "detalhes": "ok"})
    dados = request.get_json()  
    try:  
        if 'chave' not in dados: # não tem o atributo chave?
            resposta = jsonify({"resultado": "erro", 
                            "detalhes": "Atributo chave não encontrado"})
        else:
            session[dados['chave']] = dados['valor']
    except Exception as e:  # em caso de erro...
        resposta = jsonify({"resultado": "erro", "detalhes": str(e)})

    resposta.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return resposta  

@app.route('/get')
def get():
    try:
        dados = request.get_json()  
        retorno = {'resultado': 'ok'}
        retorno.update({'detalhes': session[dados['chave']]}) 
        resposta = jsonify(retorno)
    except Exception as e:  
        resposta = jsonify({"resultado": "erro", "detalhes": str(e)})
    
    resposta.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return resposta 

@app.route('/delete')
def delete():
    try:
        dados = request.get_json()  
        session.pop(dados['chave'], default=None)
        resposta = jsonify({"resultado": "ok", "detalhes": "ok"})        
    except Exception as e:  # em caso de erro...
        resposta = jsonify({"resultado": "erro", "detalhes": str(e)})
            
    resposta.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return resposta  

app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for the correct way to send cookies. `-H 'cookie: key1=val2; key2=val2;'`

cURL offers a convenience of `--cookie` as well. Run `man curl` or `tldr curl`

This was copied from Chrome > inspect >network > copy as cURL.

```
curl 'https://www.example.com/api/app/job-status/' \
  -H 'authority: www.example.com' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.111.111 Safari/111.36' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.example.com' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.example.com/app/jobs/11111111/' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cookie: menuOpen_v3=true; imageSize=medium;' \
  --data-raw '{"jobIds":["1111111111111"]}' \
  --compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using GitBash on Windows and nothing I found worked for me.

So I settled with saving my cookie to a file named `.session` and used cat to read from it like so:

```
curl -b $(cat .session) http://httpbin.org/cookies
```

And if you are curious my cookie looks like this:

```
session=abc123
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
curl -v -H 'cookie: _appname_session=lksjdflsdkj...; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax' localhost:3000/
```

Note that the session name is `_appname_session`.