# Cannot get form post body from Go gin context

Tags: forms, go, go-gin

I have updated gin-gonic and want to use it to save a form.

Here is my code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
...


func HandlePost(c *gin.Context) {
    userId, userName := getUserId(c)

    title := c.PostForm("title")
    content := c.PostForm("content")

    fmt.Println("userId is:", userId) //ok
    fmt.Println("userName is: ", userName) //ok
    fmt.Println("title is:", title) //empty
    fmt.Println("content is: ", content) //empty

...
```

I use Postman to post form, like this:

[image]

I don't get any errors but received form fields are empty. So wondering what could be wrong here and how to fix it?

Update: here is how I implemented `getUserId`:

```
func getUserId(c *gin.Context) (int, string) {
    var user []model.User
    session := sessions.Default(c)
    userEmail := session.Get("user-id").(string)
    if userEmail == "" {
        fmt.Println("userEmail NOT found")
    } else {
        err := shared.Dbmap.Select(&user, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1", userEmail)
        if err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }
    }
    return user[0].Id, user[0].UserName
}
```

Comment: How did you implement `getUserId`? I guess, when the function `getUserId` is called, it read all the request body till `EOF` so when you access the *title* and *content*, you got empty value.

Comment: @putu, I added `getUserId` function to the question. But even if when I comment out t  call to `getUserId`, the form fields are still empty.

Comment: So my initial guess was wrong, since in `getUserId` you don't read the request body. How if you try to read the form with [Context.MultipartForm() (*multipart.Form, error)](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.MultipartForm) and observe the `error`? You may also try to [inspect the Postman request](http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/06/13/debugging-postman-requests/) to see what exactly was sent to the server.

Comment: Well, I followed the official gin docs to read the form post. How can I use `c.MultipartForm` instead?

Comment: Add `form, err := c.MultipartForm()` before `title := c.PostForm("title")`. Observe the content and error by `fmt.Printf("%+v, %+v\n", form, err)`. If there was no error, you can read the value from [multipart.Form.Value](https://godoc.org/mime/multipart#Form).

Comment: I did. And now I get `<nil>, invalid URL escape "%\x00\x00"
`

Comment: Now at least we understand why you got empty value. How if you remove `file` field in the Postman request? Please also inspect the postman request to see what was exactly being sent to the server. The error message indicates that the request was invalid.

Comment: Right. removing file from post does not have any effect. I'm still struggling how to inspect the post. Can you give me curl equivalent (including cookie) so that I bypass Postman?

Comment: You can access and inspect the request through [history](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/history). For cURL and cookie, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995919/curl-how-to-send-cookies-via-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995919/curl-how-to-send-cookies-via-command-line)

Comment: Holy moly! When I post using curl, the form values are retrieves. Thanks a lot putu for solving this puzzle! Answer and I'll accept. I should ditch Postman! Here is the curl: `curl -X POST   -v --cookie "mycookename=somelonggibberish"   -F 'title=mytitle' -F 'content=mycontent' http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/post`