# Curl set cookie to header from json

Tags: php, json, curl

I have this

```
{
  "session":"59a28f4741b0800302147c4e8db00e5e",
  "id":"765611988531745",
  "rememberLogin":"76561198852231745||67b583c48e95a76fbcf7da254714e206"
}
```

how can I set this cookie to `curl` headers when i send the `POST` request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl: how to send cookies via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995919/curl-how-to-send-cookies-via-command-line)

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi i need example, please

Comment: check the link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995919/curl-how-to-send-cookies-via-command-line

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi that's not for JSON, he has some cookiejarfile, but i have json

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi i need to paste my cookie header from **JSON**, your example looks like **cookiejar**: 127.0.0.1   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   USER_TOKEN  in

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22261052/3151567

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi `array("Cookie: test=cookie")` that's not json btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curl cookie is like this: `key1=value1; key2=value2;`

So you need to convert your json to that. You can use this simple function to do that.

```php
function jsontocookie($json) {
    $ret = "";

    foreach(json_decode($json, true) as $key => $value){
        $ret .= $key."=".$value."; ";
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

And send with `CURLOPT_COOKIE`

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, jsontocookie($yourJsonData));
```

Comment: What do the dots `.` do; eg. `$ret .=  $key`

Comment: @étale-cohomology It concatenates strings. $ret .= means add the string that comes after the = to the end of the $ret variable. If you want to convert it to python it would look like this: `ret += key + "=" + value + "; "` or much simple `ret = ret + key + "=" + value + "; "`

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot