# Model Derivative API - Download OBJ File Request Headers

Tags: python-3.x, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm going through the step-by-step tutorials of how to translate a source file on the model derivative API. I'm on the final step of just downloading the OBJ file using the signed download URL and the three cookies. I have the download URL and the cookies, I just don't know how to format the headers for the request.
Like would the header look like this:

```
headers = {
'<FIRST_SIGNED_COOKIE>': '',
...
}
```

Based off that documentation, it makes it look like to me that I'm just sending a string through the header. The requests library in python doesn't seem too happy with that though.

[image]

Also, link to what I'm following: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-to-obj/task4-download-obj-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you want to include certain cookies with your request, you would use the [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header, e.g., like so:

```
curl -X GET '...' -H 'Cookie: name=value; name2=value2; name3=value3'
```

Alternatively, based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995919/how-to-use-curl-to-send-cookies), you could also say:

```
curl -X GET '...' --cookie "name=value" --cookie "name2=value2" --cookie "name3=value3"
```