# {urn}/manifest/{derivativeurn}/signedcookies - MissingKeyMissing Key-Pair-Id query

Tags: amazon-s3, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Using the following endpoint trying to set the header [Link to example](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-to-obj/task4-download-obj-file/)

```
curl -X GET  '<SIGNED_DOWNLOAD_URL>' -H '<FIRST_SIGNED_COOKIE>;<SECOND_SIGNED_COOKIE>;<THIRD_SIGNED_COOKIE>'
```

here is an example of the headers names and values from the  header of `/signedcookies`

```
Key                   Value                                                                                                                            
---                    -----                                                                                                                            
CloudFront-Policy      =eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOl2YXRpdmUuYL2RYSnVPbUZrYzJzdWQybHdaVzFsWVRwbWN5NW1hV3...
CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id APKAIJ4JBLIOQMJEURDQ; Path=/; Domain=cdn.derivative.autodesk.com; HTTPOnly                                                       
CloudFront-Signature   jFRbEY5nFXtgFgW1WqRiAHXYFwYisMotr7nwu-gRiUkc8JcgLRhQyLlPFF4CyIVbi8OOqhet-ti974...
```

However, I get the following error that suggest I'm missing a header `MissingKeyMissing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue, you need to pass the data through the url via a query rather than a header. e.g.

```
https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/XXX/output/0/properties.db?Key-Pair-Id=XXX&Signature=XXX&Policy=XXXX
```

Comment: Thanks for Tom's sharing. With this approach, we need to remove `; Path=/; Domain=cdn.derivative.autodesk.com; HTTPOnly` from the CloudFront cookie values we got from the response header.

Comment: Thanks, Tom, again for sharing the tips kindly. Here is blog post: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/download-derivative-files-using-new-signedcookies-api-without-setting-cookies-first-header

Answer (score 0):

Generally, We can specify the cookie this way:

```bash
curl -X GET  '<SIGNED_DOWNLOAD_URL>' -H 'Cookie: <FIRST_SIGNED_COOKIE>;<SECOND_SIGNED_COOKIE>;<THIRD_SIGNED_COOKIE>'
```

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74066251/7745569