# How can I get an file-like object from Selenium without download a file to a local path?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, urllib, python-3.11, bytestream

I'm working on a parser platform.
I need to download files, save them directly to the FTP server. For this I have to get file-like object. I don't want to save junk temporary files.

**I need to use selenium specifically**

For example: I need to download this [document](https://docs-prv.pcisecuritystandards.org/PCI%20DSS/Standard/PCI-DSS-v4_0.pdf), but for this I have to enter the data and accept the check.

This code passes notify and saves cookies

```py
import os
import pickle
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def get_file(driver: webdriver.Chrome, url: str):
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(40)
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(2)

    # accept notify
    ccc_accept = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ccc-notify-accept')
    if WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable(ccc_accept)):
        ccc_accept.click()

    # Enter some data
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'agreement_form')))
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'contact_name').send_keys('Company')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'contact_title').send_keys('People')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'company').send_keys('cb')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'country').send_keys('some')

    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="doc_agreement"]/div[4]/input[1]')))

    # accept form
    if WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            ec.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="doc_agreement"]/div[4]/input[1]'))):
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="doc_agreement"]/div[4]/input[1]').click()

    time.sleep(2)

    # Save cookie
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open('cookies.pkl', 'wb'))

    time.sleep(10)
```

On the web I only found a way to download a document via selenium to a local directory. This method can only install file to local_dir.

```py
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def downloadDriver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
    options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

    path_loc = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "temp")
    chrome_prefs = {
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
        "download.open_pdf_in_system_reader": False,
        "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
        "download.default_directory": path_loc,
    }
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", chrome_prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    return driver
```

I tried to get the file object via `urllib.request.urlopen()`, but it throws a 403 error
I also tried passing a cookie from Selenium to urllib, but this didn't solve the problem.

In what way can I get a stream or a file-like object or bytes, anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first comment: Here is the direct link to your file https://docs-prv.pcisecuritystandards.org/PCI%20DSS/Standard/PCI-DSS-v4_0.pdf. You don't need selenium to download it, you need a cookie otherwise you get a 403 Forbidden http response. Therefore you can use a module like `requests` and pass the cookie together with the url (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164679/how-to-send-cookies-in-a-post-request-with-the-python-requests-library)). You can even use curl directly on the command line (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995919/how-to-use-curl-to-send-cookies)). In case you want to generate the cookie without a browser and without any human intervention you can look for the URL to post the form (learn [how to use network logging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) in your browser).
- second comment: in case you really want to keep using selenium because you need to generate the cookie this way for some reason. You can use io standard library to create file-like object [How to create in-memory file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672524/how-to-create-in-memory-file-object)
- third comment: what's wrong with temporary files ? you can use temporary files that will get deleted once you close the file if you use the `with` statement (see `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` in [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html)). There is even a class to use in-memory file and disk when required. See `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile`

Comment: first comment - it really works. Thx.
for some reason, I did not try this option