# Session not staying alive/constantly changing - CURL command line

Tags: session, batch-file, curl, command-line

I am having some trouble with the CURL command line. I am trying to send a POST request to an API, which starts a new session. Now, I would like to be in the same session when I make the next request, however when I make another CURL request, it gives me a completely different session.

For example, I make the following request to a server:

```
curl -v --keepalive --data "username=username&password=password" http://example.com/login
```

The command above gives me a unique session id of something like

```
prgl4esck2hu7ge1gustnfgb35
```

Then I put in another request to a server:

```
curl -v --keepalive http://example.com/checkLogin
```

And when I put in the command above into CMD, it gives me a completely different session id. In other words, the session is not persistent and I need it to be persistent. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Please help, I have been trying to figure this out for hours now. Any help is greatly appreciated!

BTW: This works perfectly fine in Postman, so I know it has to be a problem with the curl request from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that when you say a "new session", you mean you get a new set of cookies?

You probably want to record the received cookies and then send the appropriate ones back in subsequent calls. I've detailed this in an earlier answer on [how to send cookies with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181785/send-cookies-with-curl/7186160).

[--keepalive](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--no-keepalive) is something different: it asks for TCP keep-alive to be enabled for the connection (which it already does by default).