# curl page with credentials

Tags: curl, cookies

I am trying to curl this page

http://job-search.jobstreet.com.my/malaysia/computer-information-technology-jobs/

using username and password. However, I have tried the following ways with no success

```
1. curl -c cookies.txt "login_id=xxxx&password=yyyy" https://myjobstreet.jobstreet.com.my/home/login.php?site=my&language_code=3
```

2. Download firefox "export cookies extension

either way, I generated cookies.txt from curl or firefox, then I run

```
curl -b cookies.txt http://job-search.jobstreet.com.my/malaysia/computer-information-technology-jobs/
```

It still appear that I am not logged in and can't see the salary.

Comment: I think you may have the -c and -b flags switched. From my man page: `-c, --cookie-jar <file name>` and `-b, --cookie <name=data>` can you try `curl -c "login_id=xxxx&password=yyyy" https://myjobstreet.jobstreet.com.my/home/login.php?site=my&language_code=3a`?

Comment: where did you see that from, @pherris? From my end I saw -b is to read the cookie file and -c is to start the cookie engine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181785/send-cookies-with-curl?rq=1

Comment: I just typed `man curl` in Terminal on my mac. Did it work for you?