# How to curl for extracting valid .zip file from redirecting link

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to automate a data downloading process. For this purpose, my goal is to extract (using bash commands) the .zip from a redirection link that could be seen on display here: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/suppl/10.1177/0022002706289303

I have seen that people suggest the `-L` tag with `curl` for redirections, but it doesn't seem to work for my case. The specific command I have tried is:
`curl -L -o output.zip https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/suppl/10.1177/0022002706289303/suppl_file/Sambanis_Aug_06.zip`

The command `file output.zip` shows that the extracted .zip file is actually a `HTML document text`. On the other hand, clicking the redirection link (used inside `curl` command) downloads the extracted folder automatically via a browser.

Any ideas, tips, or suggestions on what I should try (or whether this is possible or not) will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to download https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/suppl/10.1177/0022002706289303/suppl_file/Sambanis_Aug_06.zip?

Comment: Yes, using ```curl```.

Comment: The cookies seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute curl with the `--verbose` option you can see that it is a cookie related problem. The cookie engine needs to be enabled. You can download the desired file as follows:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -L https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/suppl/10.1177/0022002706289303/suppl_file/Sambanis_Aug_06.zip -o test.zip
```

It doesn't matter if the file provided with the -b option doesn't exist. We just need to activate the cookie engine.

Refer to [Send cookies with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181785/send-cookies-with-curl) and [Save cookies between two curl requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760213/save-cookies-between-two-curl-requests) for futher information.

Answer (score 1):

You can download that file with `wget` on Linux

```
$ wget https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/suppl/10.1177/0022002706289303/suppl_file/Sambanis_Aug_06.zip
$ unzip Sambanis_Aug_06.zip
Archive:  Sambanis_Aug_06.zip
inflating: Sambanis (Aug 06).dta
inflating: Sambanis Appendix (Aug 06).pdf
```

Comment: I am on Mac OS X, so I am currently restricted to ```curl```. Based on the accepted answer, it seems like ```wget``` automatically enables the cookie engine, whereas we have to provide the ```-b``` option with ```curl```. Interesting!